# Winston logging in console but not in the log files

Tags: node.js, logging, winston

I'm using Winston for logging in my project. I can see the logs in the console but there is no logging inside the log files.

Winston.js file

```
var appRoot = require('app-root-path');
var winston = require('winston');
const {transports, createLogger, format} = require('winston');
winston.addColors( winston.config.npm.colors );

const logger = winston.createLogger({
level: 'info',
format: format.combine(
    format.timestamp({format:'MM-YY-DD hh:mm:ss a'}),
    format.json(),

),
transports: [
  new winston.transports.File({ filename: './logs/error.log', level: 'error' }),
  new winston.transports.File({  handleExceptions: true,colorize:true,
    json: true,filename: './logs/app.log',
})
]
  });
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
logger.add(new winston.transports.Console({
  format: winston.format.simple()
}));
  }
module.exports = logger;
```

Server.js code

```
var morgan = require('morgan');
var winston = require('./server/config/winston');
```

Node version
 8.11.3

Winston version
 3.1.0

Comment: Does the folder `./logs` exist before running the code?

Comment: yes @WilliamChong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure 'logs' folder exists. Winston doesnt take care of non-existent folder, nor giving any warning or errors.

You can put following code in your server.js

```
var fs = require( 'fs' );
var logDir = 'logs';
if ( !fs.existsSync( logDir ) ) {
   fs.mkdirSync( logDir );
}
winston.info('Hey NODE');
```

Using the absolute folder path inside the winston.js solved the problem.

Comment: Well, I tried running your code. It works well with my suggestion. There are chances that you are running your code not from project root.
You can specify absolute folder path in your winston.js

Comment: Using your above-mentioned code same thing happens, log only shows up in the console and not inside the log file.